# Link on text file doesn't open

Tags: html, hyperlink

I am creating lots of link in my page and mostly the text file is being opened when user click on link. But some files are being downloaded. I cannot understand why, because the format is the same (file name is dat_chsa_create_existing.2.diff)
DIFF

Comment: If browser does not know how to open it, it will try to download that file.

Comment: I understand, but I mostly it opens the files. Only some of them are being downloaded. And the files which are opened have the same format. This happens on chrome and mozilla

Comment: Double-checked extension AND mime-type?

Comment: Yeah, have checked once more

Comment: try to check that the DIFF files will open with witch software!